Error: Assert failed: This browser/engine doesn't support WASM SIMD. Please use a modern version
I'm working in a blazor wasm hosted app, it actually works when it runs in visual studio and when I publish the app in IIS it works to. The problem starts when I copy and paste the publish to IIS in another server.
It gives me a lot of errors, but it all look like the next one:
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Error in mono_download_assets: Error: Assert failed: This browser/engine doesn't support WASM SIMD. Please use a modern version. See also https://aka.ms/dotnet-wasm-features
there are like 7 times this error.
I understand that the problem could be WASM SIMD, so I disabled it, but it didnt work.
The project is called Risk, and this is Risk.Server.csproject:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <WasmEnableSIMD>false</WasmEnableSIMD>
      <BlazorWebAssemblyJiterpreter>false</BlazorWebAssemblyJiterpreter>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.7">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\Risk.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Risk.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>

As you can see, I disabled the SIMD on this line: <WasmEnableSIMD>false</WasmEnableSIMD>.
and this is my index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Risk</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Risk.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/software-base.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>  
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.downloadFile = async (fileName, byteArray) => {
            const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(byteArray)]);
            const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
            anchorElement.href = url;
            anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
            anchorElement.click();
            anchorElement.remove();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    </script>


</body>

</html>

I really dont know what else to do, if anyone can help, I'll apreciate that.

I encountered this error in a hosted Blazor wasm App when surfing to the app on certain Windows Server OSes, I added this to the csproj of the CLIENT app:
<PropertyGroup>
   ...
  <WasmEnableExceptionHandling>false</WasmEnableExceptionHandling>
  <WasmEnableSIMD>false</WasmEnableSIMD>
</PropertyGroup>

Nothing was added in the server project.

It seems to work, but the it droped a new error: MONO_WASM: AllowRange:3e code generation failed: CompileError: WebAssembly.Module(): Compiling function #0 failed: Wasm SIMD unsupported @+156 CompileError: WebAssembly.Module(): Compiling function #0 failed: Wasm SIMD unsupported @+156

delete obj and bin files and rebuild everything, this seems odd ...

It didnt work, besides there was another error:  dotnet.runtime.8.0.7.urcsr75yt5.js:3 MONO_WASM: get_Cache:0 code generation failed: CompileError: WebAssembly.Module(): Compiling function #1 failed: Wasm SIMD unsupported @+160 CompileError: WebAssembly.Module(): Compiling function #1 failed: Wasm SIMD unsupported @+160

you could experiment with the other wasm project settings, e.g. try adding "true" to the client csproj

Since the app runs smoothly from VS and when hosted locally using IIS but not when deploying on a separate server, I guess this is not really an SIMD issue (if I understand right that you access the hosted app through the same browser you used for all of the three scenarios), because almost all browsers now have a JS engine that that can execute the WASM code with SIMD support.
You can try to bypass the error for now by using a small script in index.html:
<script>
    window.Module = {
        onRuntimeInitialized: function () {
            Module.onAbort = function (error) {
                if (error.includes('This browser/engine doesn\'t support WASM SIMD')) {
                    console.error('Disabling SIMD');
                    Module.simd = false;
                    location.reload();
                }
            };
        }
    };
</script>

It basically waits for the WebAssembly runtime to fully initialize and handles the SIMD error on aborting by disabling SIMD and reloading the app.

thanks for your answer, I tried it but the problem persists, it could be a problem of the browser of the other server or maybe some missing resource? I have already installed on the dotnet-hosting server, dotnet runtime and the url rewrite, all with .net 8 version, and also the following:
'dotnet workload install wasm-tools'
'dotnet workload install wasm-experimental'
